# how can i move an element within a list of images? with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a list of images

```
<img src="image-1.jpg" />
<img src="image-2.jpg" />
<img src="image-3.jpg" />
<img src="image-4.jpg" />
<img src="image-5.jpg" />
```

whats the best way to reorder them such that image-1 is at the bottom? (but not necessarily image-1)

**Edit:** Preferably without using anything like the JQuery UI.
I would like this to be done with as little code as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not trying to create a dynamic sortable list and are just looking for a way to re-order images.  You could try the following.

```
$("img[src$='image-1.jpg']").insertAfter("img[src$='image-5.jpg']");
```

This will allow you to find images and move them around based on the src of the image.

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Look at the different methods that are available for DOMinsertion.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy

```
$(function(){

    var parent=$("img").parent();
    $("img:first").appendTo(parent);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the jQuery UI:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

(Supposing you want this to be dynamic, if not you should further explain the exact situation)

Answer (score 0):

Then you want like something this? It sorts 1,2,3,4,5 to 5,4,3,2,1

```
<div id="reorder">
    <img src="http://www.google.com.tr/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
    <img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/logo/20100909/yahoo_logo_tr.png" />
    <img src="http://www.rev2.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/bing-logo.png" />
    <img src="http://a.l.yimg.com/a/i/us/sch/yhs4/altavista_logo.png" />
    <img src="http://searchcdn.infospace.com/Dogpile-8.0.1.353/Content/Img/img_trans.gif?av=1353" />
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#reorder').click(function() {
            $("#reorder").randomize("img");
        });
    });

    (function($) {
        var onerandom = Math.random();
        $.fn.randomize = function(childElem) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var elems = $this.children(childElem);
                elems.sort(function() { return (Math.round(onerandom)-0.5); });  
                $this.remove(childElem);  
                for(var i=0; i < elems.length; i++)
                $this.append(elems[i]);      
            });    
        }
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```